# When is a Windows-Server more vulnerable

Tags: windows-update, windows-server

**Context**
Sometimes when a new update for a windows-server comes available it would be possible for me to install the updates but can't restart the server.

For restarting the server I need to be present because the hardware sometimes is acting strange by hanging in the initialization step. When this happens I need to manual power-off the server and afterwards power-on the server again.

And yes, the installation and restart should take place when nobody is working anymore, so I usually do this either in the morning before my peers arrive or in the evening when they have left.
Now like today, I came later as them and I will leave earlier and in addition will have the next 2 days vacation.

**Question**
Is the server more vulnerable if I **postpone the update and restart** of the server till e.g Monday or if I install the updates today **but postpone the restart** of the server till e.g Monday?

Comment: What should be done is entirely determined by a combination of factors including but not limited to the severity of the vulnerability, how exploitable and the likelihood the vulnerability will be exploited, and the overall risk determination of performing a reboot. You can mitigate the situation by having primary and secondary servers. Just make sure you test your failover situations unlike Github did a few years ago. Windows updates are not implemented until they are installed, which happens at reboot, so pending updates don’t offer protection against vulnerabilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're between a rock & a hard place, because to my mind your peak danger zone is after the updates have been installed, but the services not yet moved into place & activated.

At that point, a hang or power outage could wreck that handover. It *shouldn't* happen, the update procedure ought to be robust enough to survive that, but there's always a small possibility.

…but your machine has a possibility of hanging anyway at reboot.

So, even though you have the potential of it hanging, like the Sword of Damocles over you, you're still marginally safer to not start the update until you can be there to supervise the entire process.